# Setting up tornado in mac

Tags: python, installation, tornado

I'm new to using mac and tornado. I have installed easy_install and tried installing tornado but I am keep getting "Permission denied"

easy_install tornado

Searching for tornado
Best match: tornado 2.3
Processing tornado-2.3-py2.7.egg
Adding tornado 2.3 to easy-install.pth file
error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth: Permission denied

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it like this:

sudo easy_install tornado

When you are using stock python on OSX the easy_install command will install tornado system wide and it therefore needs admin rights. When using homebrew python (e.g. installed brew and python with "brew install python") then you can install python packages without having to do the sudo.

One word of advice: when working on a lot of python projects it's better to use virtualenv for installing python deps; that way you can have multiple isolated python environments AND you don't need the sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try running that command as root if you want to install tornado system-wide or take a look at `virtualenv` for installing python packages in a sandboxed environment. Also, I recommend `pythonbrew` if you want to experiment with various versions of Python.

Comment: Well I was in home directory running that, And i did cd / and went to root directory, but I still get the same Permission denied error

Comment: Its kind of weird actually. When I go to site_package the tornado folder is there! but I can not import it in the Idle ?